# Hadoop Hive unable to move source to destination

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, execution

I am trying to use Hive 1.2.0 over Hadoop 2.6.0. I have created an `employee` table. However, when I run the following query:

```
hive> load data local inpath '/home/abc/employeedetails' into table employee;
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed with exception Unable to move source file:/home/abc/employeedetails to destination hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/employee/employeedetails_copy_1
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask
```

What wrong am I doing here? Are there any specific permissions that I need to set? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Rio, the issue involved lack of permissions to load data into hive table. I figures out the following command solves my problems:

```
hadoop fs -chmod g+w /user/hive/warehouse
```

Answer (score 3):

See the permission for the HDFS directory:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/employee/employeedetails_copy_1
```

Seems like you may not have permission to load data into hive table.

Answer (score 0):

The error might be due to permission issue on local filesystem.

Change the permission for local filesystem:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/abc/employeedetails
```

Now, run:

```
hive> load data local inpath '/home/abc/employeedetails' into table employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

If we face same error After running the above command in distributed mode,    we can try the the below cammand in all super users of all nodes.
**sudo usermod -a -G hdfs yarn** 
 Note:we get this error after restart the all the services of YARN(in AMBARI).My problem was resolved.This is admin command better to care when you are running.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problems and search it two days .Finally I find the reason is that datenode  start a moment and shut down.

solve steps:

1. `hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /home/abc/employeedetails`
2. `hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/hive/warehouse/employee/employeedetails_copy_1`
3. `vi hdfs-site.xml` and add follow infos :

   dfs.permissions.enabled
   false
4. `hdfs --daemon start datanode`
5. `vi hdfs-site.xml`  #find the location of 'dfs.datanode.data.dir'and'dfs.namenode.name.dir'.If it is the same location ,you must change it ,this is why I can't start datanode reason.
6. follow 'dfs.datanode.data.dir'/data/current edit the VERSION and copy clusterID to 'dfs.namenode.name.dir'/data/current clusterID of VERSION。
7. `start-all.sh`
8. if above it is unsolved , to be careful to follow below steps because of the safe of data ,but I already solve the problem because follow below steps.
9. `stop-all.sh`
10. delete the data folder of 'dfs.datanode.data.dir' and  the data folder of 'dfs.namenode.name.dir' and tmp folder.
11. `hdfs namenode -format`
12. `start-all.sh`
13. solve the problem

maybe you will meet other problem like this.

problems:

> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException):
>   Cannot create directory
>   /opt/hive/tmp/root/1be8676a-56ac-47aa-ab1c-aa63b21ce1fc. Name node is
>   in safe mode

methods: `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave`

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your hive user does not have the access to the **HDFS' local directories**