# Hive table fail to load data from Local

Tags: hadoop, hive

**Command-**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/user/sample.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE employee;
```

**Error:**

> Unable to move source file:/home/user/sample.txt to destination
>   hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/employee/sample.txt;

I have changed the permission for folder as well as in hdfs.

But getting same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop Hive unable to move source to destination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483296/hadoop-hive-unable-to-move-source-to-destination)

Answer (score 0):

Amar,

It's due to permission issue

Please run the below commands:

sudo chmod -R 777 /home/user/

hadoop fs -chmod g+w /user/hive/warehouse