# Hive error with attempt to do update table that is not transactional

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to update a temporary table on hive by using the following command:

```
alter table para1 add columns(log_flag int);
update para1 set log_flag = (
  case 
            when name like '%LANDING__TIME' then 1 
            when name like '%LOGIN_START_TIME' then 2
            when name like '%LOGIN_TIME' then 3
            else 4
  end
  );
```

Following is the error I received:

> ERROR: Execute error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:
>   Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException 
>           [Error 10297]: Attempt to do update or delete on table df.para1 that is not transactional

This prevents me to update the table with the new conditional variable log_flag, and I'm really not sure what is the cause.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [INSERT OVERWRITE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Syntax.1) for non-transactional table:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE table para1
select 
     col1, ... coln, --list all other columns (columns positions should match)
     case 
            when name like '%LANDING__TIME'    then 1 
            when name like '%LOGIN_START_TIME' then 2
            when name like '%LOGIN_TIME'       then 3
            else 4
    end as log_flag 
from para1;
```

Comment: Here is the error I received:  ERROR: Execute error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask. Unable to move source 
        hdfs://... to destination 
        hdfs://....

Comment: @lydias Check exception details on the task tracker. Looks like some configuration or permissions issue

Comment: @lydias Also search the same issue. For example this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30483296/2700344

Comment: Using this inserts the desired values, but throws the same exception at non-transactional table, is there any way to suppress the error?